# Can GitHub pages automatically build a Jekyll site on commit to gh-pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am learning how to use jekyll and would love it if someone could explain how to set it up so that whenever I commit the jekyll files to the gh-pages branch, the site would be automatically generated.

Thank you

Comment: That is exactly [how it works](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) already.

Comment: I am graphic designer by trade so forgive my ignorance, I have installed jekyll and committed the files with some test markdown files in the _posts folder and it does not automatically build those pages.

Comment: @ZackGemmell, have you pushed those commits to GitHub?

Comment: You need to upload the whole site to GitHub after the repository is configured to host your website. The only folder you must not upload is `_site`. For an overview please check this [article](http://blog.virtuacreative.com.br/free-hosting-website-github.html), where we go step-by-step to publishing your website on GitHub. After the repo is set, just upload everything and make sure you added a [Gemfile](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) whith this content: `source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'` to the site root.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty and others, I don't see anywhere in the GitHub  documentation where they actually discuss how deploying works and what does or does not happen automatically; only which branch to deploy to.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) pointed by @thirtythreeforty's comment

> For User Pages, use the **master** branch in your username.github.io repository. For Project Pages, use the **gh-pages** branch in your project's repository.

- if your repository is at github.com/userName/userName.github.io it's your **user** repo -> publish to **master**
- any other repository like github.com/userName/projectName is a project repository -> publish to **gh-pages**

So, be sure to commit in the right branch.

If the problem is elsewhere you can give your repository url for further investigation.

Comment: As of August 2016, it is no longer necessary to use a `gh-pages` branch. See https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing